# How to call Oracle function or stored procedure using spring persistence framework?

Tags: spring, oracle, junit

I am using Spring persistence framework for my project.
I want to call oracle function or stored procedure from this framework.

Can anybody suggest how can I achieve this.

Please give solution for both * oracle function and *stored procedure.

Thanks.

Comment: Spring has a persistence framework? Are you referring to Spring's JdbcTemplate? Or Hibernate?

Comment: I have used DPTK to create persistence framework and Spring's query factory. Now want to call oracle function or stored procedure using existing functionality, can u help me to sort this..

Comment: DPTK appears to be an IBM product: http://www.alphaworks.ibm.com/tech/dptk

Comment: I don't get the relation to junit. Could you please provide this information?

Answer (score 34):

Assuming you are referring to JdbcTemplate:

```
jdbcTemplate.execute(
    new CallableStatementCreator() {
        public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException{
            CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call MY_STORED_PROCEDURE(?, ?, ?)}");
            cs.setInt(1, ...); // first argument
            cs.setInt(2, ...); // second argument
            cs.setInt(3, ...); // third argument
            return cs;
        }
    },
    new CallableStatementCallback() {
        public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) throws SQLException{
            cs.execute();
            return null; // Whatever is returned here is returned from the jdbcTemplate.execute method
        }
    }
);
```

Calling a function is almost identical:

```
jdbcTemplate.execute(
    new CallableStatementCreator() {
        public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) {
            CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{? = call MY_FUNCTION(?, ?, ?)}");
            cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER); // or whatever type your function returns.
            // Set your arguments
            cs.setInt(2, ...); // first argument
            cs.setInt(3, ...); // second argument
            cs.setInt(4, ...); // third argument
            return cs;
        }
    },
    new CallableStatementCallback {
        public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) {
            cs.execute();
            int result = cs.getInt(1);
            return result; // Whatever is returned here is returned from the jdbcTemplate.execute method
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: here we are calling SP, how can we call Oracle Function...I m not referring to JdbcTemplate, I am reffering persistence framework using DPTK..

Comment: The second example is calling a function. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with DPTK. Does it have a web site?

Comment: okay, I will try to implement this with my code...hope it will work..Thanks Adam, will let you know the result..

Comment: You don't have to use this. I just didn't know what the Spring persistence framework was. This was just my best guess.

Comment: DPTK(Design Patter Tool Kit) is a RAD plug-in, unfortunately i don't have any web site for it right now, once get I will send it to you..

Answer (score 19):

Simpler way of calling a Oracle function in Spring is subclassing StoredProcedure like below

```
public class MyStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure{
    private static final String SQL = "package.function";

    public MyStoredProcedure(DataSource ds){
        super(ds,SQL);
        declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter("param_out",Types.NUMERIC));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("param_in",Types.NUMERIC));
        setFunction(true);//you must set this as it distinguishes it from a sproc
        compile();
    }

    public String execute(Long rdsId){
        Map in = new HashMap();
        in.put("param_in",rdsId);
        Map out = execute(in);
        if(!out.isEmpty())
            return out.get("param_out").toString();
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

And call it like this

```
@Autowired DataSource ds;
MyStoredProcedure sp = new MyStoredProcedure(ds);
String i = sp.execute(1l);
```

The Oracle function used here just takes in a numeric parameter and returns a numeric paramter.

Comment: as i understand the SQL code should look like: `{:param_out = call schema.package.MY_FUNCTION(:param_in)}`

Comment: my last comment is wrong. the SQL constant has to contain only the procedure/function name, like `schema.package.MY_FUNCTION`, and the parameter names in Java **HAVE** to match the parameter names as defined in the procedure/function.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this is one of the easiest approaches:

```
public class ServRepository {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private SimpleJdbcCall functionGetServerErrors;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);
        this.functionGetServerErrors = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withFunctionName("THIS_IS_YOUR_DB_FUNCTION_NAME").withSchemaName("OPTIONAL_SCHEMA_NAME");
    }

        public String callYourFunction(int parameterOne, int parameterTwo) {
            SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("DB_FUNCTION_INCOMING_PARAMETER_ONE", parameterOne).addValue("DB_FUNCTION_INCOMING_PARAMETER_TWO", parameterTwo);
            return functionGetServerErrors.executeFunction(String.class, in);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why not `new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)`?

Comment: @Alex78191 you would need to write SQL there. I'm trying to stay agnostic.

Comment: No, everything else is the same.

Comment: @Alex78191 can you please provide an example answer with SimpleJdbcCall? I don't remember why I went with this solution tbh

Comment: @Alex78191 that one has SQL. I went with this solution, because it was pure java and quite simple.

Comment: > `new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
        .withCatalogName("MY_PACKAGE")
        .withFunctionName("MY_FUNCTION")
        .executeFunction(String.class, "arg1", "arg2")`

Answer (score 1):

Calling function using `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`:

```
final String query = "select MY_FUNCTION(:arg1, :arg2, :arg3) from dual";
Map<String, Object> argMap = new HashMap<>();
argMap.put("arg1", "value1");
argMap.put("arg2", 2);
argMap.put("arg3", "value3");
final String result = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource)
        .queryForObject(query, argMap, String.class);
```

Calling procedure using `JdbcTemplate`:

```
final String query = "call MY_PROCEDURE(?, ?, ?)";
final Object[] args = {"arg1", "arg2", "arg3"};
new JdbcTemplate(dataSource).execute(query, args, String.class);
```

Calling function using `SimpleJdbcCall`:

```
Map<String, Object> inParameters = new HashMap<>();
inParameters.put("arg1", 55); // arg1 value
inParameters.put("arg2", 20); // arg2 value
MapSqlParameterSource mapSqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParameters);
BigDecimal result = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
        .withCatalogName("MY_PACKAGE")
        .withSchemaName("MY_SCHEMA")
        .withFunctionName("MY_FUNCTION")
        .executeFunction(BigDecimal.class, mapSqlParameterSource);
```

Calling procedure using `SimpleJdbcCall`:

```
new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
        .withCatalogName("MY_PACKAGE")
        .withProcedureName("MY_PROCEDURE")
        .execute("arg1", arg2);
```