# calling a mysql function returning varchar in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, string, hibernate, function

I am trying to use mysql `find_in_set` string function in hibernate but unfortunately I cant able to use it and even tried by creating these register functions

```
registerFunction("findInSet",newSQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.STRING,"FIND_IN_SET(?1,?2)"));
registerFunction("findInSet",newSQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.INTEGER,"FIND_IN_SET(?1,?2)"));
registerFunction("findInSet",new StandardSQLFunction("find_in_set", Hibernate.INTEGER));
```

using mysqldialect but no one is working..can any one please tell me how to use the mysql string functions in hibernate. or any changes to the above register functions.

Thanks in Advance,

Best Regards,
Raja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created a class by extending mysqldialect like shown below

```
public class MySqlDialectExtended extends MySQLDialect {

public MySqlDialectExtended() {
    super();
    registerFunction("date_add_interval", new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.DATE, "date_add(?1, INTERVAL ?2 ?3)"));
    registerFunction("date_sub_interval", new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.DATE, "DATE_SUB(?1, INTERVAL ?2 ?3)"));
    registerFunction("weekofyear", new StandardSQLFunction("weekofyear", Hibernate.INTEGER));
    registerFunction("group_concat", new StandardSQLFunction("group_concat", Hibernate.STRING));
}
```

}

and used it like this in query

```
new Query(" >= date_sub_interval(CURRENT_DATE(),1, DAY)");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to call a function **if your function is returning a `string or varchar` value**.

`session.createSQLQuery("select my_super_fn(:param1)")`

Where **my_super_fn** is the name of your function with parameter **param1**.

To test the syntax try this code which gets you the current server date.

```
Date d = (Date)session.createSQLQuery("select CURDATE()").uniqueResult();
System.out.println(d);
```

For other type of functions refer a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862694/how-to-call-oracle-function-or-stored-procedure-using-spring-persistence-framewo) on how to do it.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply..but the idea you gave is not working in this format.  Query query = this.entityManager.createQuery("select FIND_IN_SET()")..can u please give me an idea how to use with entity managers in hibernate.

Comment: are you using JPA? What error is you getting? In the meanwhile you should use the **[createNativeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String))**.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
package mypackage;

import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.SQLFunctionTemplate;
import org.hibernate.type.BooleanType;

public class CustomSqlDialect extends MySQL5InnoDBDialect {
    public CustomSqlDialect() {
        registerFunction("find_in_set", new SQLFunctionTemplate(IntegerType.INSTANCE, "find_in_set(?1, ?2)");
    }
}
```

And set this in your JPA configuration file:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="mypackage.CustomSqlDialect"/>
```

Finally ,for `find_in_set` you should make sure the query conditional is `find_in_set(...) > 0`.  Using `find_in_set()` without the comparison operator will fail to execute with an AST error.

Also, you should obviously override the appropriate dialect and package name.