# How to call procedure in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, stack-overflow

First time I am trying to call procedure in hibernate like -

```
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getFirstFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = getSession().getNamedQuery("select");
        q.setInteger("locationid", locId);
        cDbInsts = (List<SpCustsitesettings>) q.list();
```

MY hbm file SpCustsitesettings.hbm.xml is -

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="glb.chatmeter.db.SpCustsitesettings">
    <id name="cmcustLocId" type="int">
        <column name="CMCustLocID"/>
    </id>
    <property name="cpid" type="string">
        <column name="CPID">
        </column>
    </property>
</class>
<sql-query name="select" callable="true">
    <return alias="select" class="glb.chatmeter.db.SpCustsitesettings">
        <return-property name="cmcustLocId" column="CMCustLocID" />
        <return-property name="cpid" column="CPID" />
    </return>
    <query-param name="locationid" type="int" />
{call select(:locationid)}
</sql-query>
```

and I have added this in config file like -

```
<mapping resource="xml/SpCustsitesettings.hbm.xml"/>
```

But when I goes to execute my query showing an exception -

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at gnu.xml.pipeline.ValidationConsumer$ChildrenRecognizer.patchNext(ValidationConsumer.java:1570)
    at gnu.xml.pipeline.ValidationConsumer$ChildrenRecognizer.patchNext(ValidationConsumer.java:1591)
    at gnu.xml.pipeline.ValidationConsumer$ChildrenRecognizer.patchNext(ValidationConsumer.java:1580)
    at gnu.xml.pipeline.ValidationConsumer$ChildrenRecognizer.patchNext(ValidationConsumer.java:1580)
    at gnu.xml.pipeline.ValidationConsumer$ChildrenRecognizer.patchNext(ValidationConsumer.java:1591)
.............................................................................
```

And Program going turn off.
Here is my Procedure -

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `select`(IN locationid INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT cmcustLocId, cpid FROM `custsitesettings` WHERE `CMCustLocID` = locationid;
END
```

What is the problem I am not following can any one help me.

Comment: Looks like it got into an infinite loop somewhere. What's at the bottom of the stack, after the huge number of `patchNext` calls?

Comment: Paste the code of from where you are calling ValidationConsumer.java, patchNext().. It is getting called in infinite loop.

Comment: No, I have no any file like ValidationConsumer.java. And in my code I am not using any loop. I think ValidationConsumer.java is predefine code/class.

Comment: ValidationConsumer is gnu library code for xml parsing.

Comment: Yeah correct ValidationConsumer parsing xml.

Comment: Checkout there may be more stack trace than that of you have pasted. I might help

Comment: You can simplify the usage with a function inside the **select** query if it returns a string as told here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8356560/507864.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within your mapping file `SpCustsitesettings.hbm.xml`.

Change

```
<hibernate-mapping>
.....

  <sql-query name="select" callable="true">
      <return alias="select" class="glb.chatmeter.db.SpCustsitesettings">
        <return-property name="cmcustLocId" column="CMCustLocID" />
         <return-property name="cpid" column="CPID" />
     </return>
     <query-param name="locationid" type="int" />
    {call select(:locationid)}
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

to

```
<sql-query name="select" callable="true">
    <return alias="select" class="glb.chatmeter.db.SpCustsitesettings">
        <return-property name="cmcustLocId" column="CMCustLocID" />
        <return-property name="cpid" column="CPID" />
    </return>
    <query-param name="locationid" type="int" />
    <![CDATA[CALL select(:locationid)]]>
</sql-query>
```

Comment: Check your hibernate mapping dos it missing </hibernate-mapping>