# How to get row of table in which column contains some value.?

Tags: mysql

I have TBL_STD_FIELD_VALUE table, in that FLD_USER_IDS column is present.
It's datatype is varchar(255). I am storing email ids separated by ',' in that column.

Below is FLD_USER_IDS column values.

[image: Query one]

I want to retrieve rows, in which FLD_USER_IDS column contains **'akshay_goel2013@isb.gappspilot.info'** entry.

Below is my sql query

```
select fieldValues.FLD_USER_IDS from TBL_STD_FIELD_VALUE as fieldValues where 'akshay_goel2013@isb.gappspilot.info'  IN (fieldValues.FLD_USER_IDS)
```

But it is not giving any result. is something wrong in it.?

Comment: Storing values as csv is very bad db design. Think about normalizing your db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `FIND_IN_SET` for more information see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

This query should give you the correct result:

```
select fieldValues.FLD_USER_IDS from TBL_STD_FIELD_VALUE as fieldValues where FIND_IN_SET ('akshay_goel2013@isb.gappspilot.info',fieldValues.FLD_USER_IDS)
```

Comment: @shree.pat18: If you have downvoted here, better remove it. :)

Comment: No, I haven't. I left a comment as the answer solves the original question so downvoting is stupid!

Comment: @Downvoter please explain. Why you downvote a correct answer.

Comment: @ Jens. Actually I am using hibernate. I found that it is not working with hibernate. can you give some hint about how to handle above issues using hibernate..

Comment: @RBP Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355719/calling-a-mysql-function-returning-varchar-in-hibernate). This should help.