# How to check if field contains a specific value in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select

A table field type string can contain comma separated int values e.g. "1,6,2,13" or "3,9,2" or "1,3"

How can I select all entries which are containing e.g. "3" not getting the "13"?

A `select * from table where field like '%3%'` will not work in that case.
Nor `like '%,3,%`

Currently I'm trying all combinations: '3,%' , '%,3' , '%,3,%', but I'm wondering if there's a more easy way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get row of table in which column contains some value.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297830/how-to-get-row-of-table-in-which-column-contains-some-value)

Comment: Storing values as csv is very bad database design.

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE` won't work for exact search, Better to use REGEX to get exact search

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
    field  REGEXP '[[<:]]3[[:>]]'
```

Or you can also use `FIND_IN_SET()` function

```
SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE 
    FIND_IN_SET('3', field ) > 0
```

NOTE: `FIND_IN_SET()` function won't work correctly if tags not symmetric comma separated, if tags have white space between , then it would create problem

Comment: I'm not a fan of regular expressions, can be slow sometimes. But I like the function FIND_IN_SET, this function was unknown for me.

Comment: see more details about `find_in_set()` function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE field REGEXP '^3,|,3,|,3$';
```