# How to deal with find_in_set in hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

For "**Student**" table, There is column as "**Friend-Names**".
In that column values are "**rahul,kuldeep,rachana,vivek"** etc.

I have to get those records from "Student" table, for which "Friend-Names" column contains "kuldeep".

I got **find_in_set** keyword but it is not working with hibernate. 
can anyone tell me how to handle such case using hibernate ? how to deal with such cases without or with find_in_set using hibernate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling a mysql function returning varchar in hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355719/calling-a-mysql-function-returning-varchar-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm almost sure, that hibernate does not supply find_in_set function. So, you can do two things -

1. you can declare find_in_set function for mysql dialect (bad decision, because it will work only with mysql)
2. You can remake your database structure, and keep friend-names in other table. Than just add join to it.

second case is better.