# Group by a string with delimiter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where i save for every record his ancestors

```
+----+------------+
| id | ancestors  |
+----+------------+
|  1 | ,1,        |
|  2 | ,2,        |
|  3 | ,3,1,      |
|  4 | ,4,2,      |
|  5 | ,5,3,1,    |
|  6 | ,6,4,2,    |
|  7 | ,7,5,3,1,  |
+----+------------+
```

How to group by `id` but like this way `group by ','id','` and not `group by id` to get a result like this :

```
+----+------------+
| id | count      |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 4          |
|  2 | 3          |
|  3 | 3          |
|  4 | 2          |
|  5 | 2          |
|  6 | 1          |
|  7 | 1          |
+----+------------+
```

My requirement is to find the count of the `id` in the whole column of `ancestors`.

Comment: Please provide more details: schema details, table structure/details, full query being used. An SQLFiddle would be much better, of course!

Comment: That is a violating of the basic rules of normalization.  The ancestors table should have multiple rows with an atomic value for ancestor.  Assuming you have 2 parents, you'd have maximum 2 rows.     Also your example doesn't seem to make sense.  For id 1, you have 1 as an ancestor?  Why?  You aren't your own parent.

Comment: @gview following always the rules of normalizations it's not always the best choice just be carfull and choice the the solution who fit your problem .. in my case i can't make a query to find all the descending of a record if i respect normalization

Comment: In this case you are completely incorrect.  You certainly can get the answer and it's even optimized in some databases.  Even in mysql it is doable:  https://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/

Comment: I won't go into the specifics of why your design is wrongheaded, but good luck keeping that column updated.  You will be doing a LIKE '%something%' query which can't use an index.  Having an entry indicating that something is a parent of itself is silly.  You could return count+1.   It seems you are not good at exploring answers.  The one you accepted doesn't use an index, but you discounted the better answer due to his warning you that there are efficiency concerns.

Comment: @gview I'm using `JPA/Hibernate` and `FIND_IN_SET` didn't work on it, what i'm suppose to do ?

Comment: Your structure is still bad, and probably has substantial issues you haven't articulated yet.  We have one simple example, but one can assume that you would need to do more than return a count of ancestors in the actual application.  As for hibernate, you should probably make another question.  Using find_in_set with your stack was answered here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355719/calling-a-mysql-function-returning-varchar-in-hibernate. None of these are going to use an index, as i've stated multiple times.  This should tell you something about your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement seems to be to find the `count` of the `id` in the whole column of `ancestors`.

Hence, the using `COUNT` in a dependent subquery should be fine, as below:

```
SELECT a.id, 
(SELECT count(*) FROM ancestors_table t where t.ancestors LIKE CONCAT('%,',a.id,',%') )
  FROM ancestors_table a;
```

Working SQLFiddle [here.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7e90d5/3)

UPDATE: Fixed the issue for two-digit or more figures. 1 will match only 1. Not 10, 11, etc. This is possible because your column appends `,` around each and every value.

Comment: Yes that's my requirement but what about performance and `concat` or `REGEXP` operator ?

Comment: This will return incorrect results as soon as you have two-digit or more figures. 1 will match not only 1 but 10, 11 etc.

Comment: @Quassnoi with `concat` operation is it more faster than `FIND_IN_SET` ?

Comment: @Youssef: no, it is not

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT  m1.id, COUNT(*)
FROM    mytable m1
JOIN    mytable m2
ON      FIND_IN_SET(m1.id, m2.ancestors)
GROUP BY
        m1.id
```

Note that it's not an efficient method and it will become slower as your database grows larger.

Comment: thanks man but i didn't understand `FIND_IN_SET` function and i use it on a search method i'm afraid it slow down the request.. also this work on `jpa` or `hibenrate` ?

Comment: Yes, as I said this function is not index-friendly. It will work in any system capable of submitting this query to MySQL. You could possibly improve this using `FULLTEXT` indexing, but `MATCH` unfortunately does not work in a join condition in MySQL.