# Using TRIM LEADING function with HQL and MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql, trim

I'm doing query on the database to check about phone number range overlapping each other.

Some numbers are stored as having a '+' char in front : +332457896 and other are stored without it : 332457897.

So before doing comparaison I want to remove the potential leading '+'.

I found the MySQL Trim function which works fine in MySQL Workbench or even with  hibernate using native query :

```
TRIM(LEADING '+' FROM MyColumn)
```

But when I try to do the same using hibernate HQL query, I get an error :

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter -  Path expected for join!

I'm guessing it has to do with the 'From' keyword.

I checked and Trim function is supported by EJB-QL 3.0 and its syntax is :

> trim([leading | trailing | both]  [from] String)

EDIT : here is the java code I used to execute this query

startNumber and endNumber are the full phone number for the range I'm trying to create.
And I check it against the Range table from which I build existing rangeStart and rangeEnd number by concataining prefix and rangeStart / rangeEnd column.

```
public List<Range> findRangeOverlap(String pStartNumber, String pEndNumber) {
    StringBuilder jpaQuerySb = new StringBuilder("SELECT p FROM MyTable p ");

    // Overlap restriction
    // For readability extract the string to build the start and end number for all the other range
    String otherStart = "TRIM(LEADING '+' FROM CONCAT(IFNULL(p.prefix, ''), IFNULL(p.rangeStart, ''))) ";
    String otherEnd = "TRIM(LEADING '+' FROM CONCAT(IFNULL(p.prefix, ''), IFNULL(p.rangeEnd, ''))) ";

    // Then check for overlap
    jpaQuerySb.append("where ( (:start >= ").append(otherStart);
    jpaQuerySb.append("and :start <= ").append(otherEnd).append(")");
    jpaQuerySb.append("or ( :end >= ").append(otherStart);
    jpaQuerySb.append("and :end <= ").append(otherEnd).append("))");

    Query q = entityManager().createQuery(jpaQuerySb.toString());
    q.setParameter("start", pStartNumber);
    q.setParameter("end", pEndNumber);

    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Does this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355719/calling-a-mysql-function-returning-varchar-in-hibernate ?

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this is already how I'm doing it, the concat work fine it's just the FROM keyword needed by the TRIM function which only has 1 parameter which block, I think.

Comment: what about generally adding + if there's none?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Added the HQL query generated in the main post 1h ago

Comment: Not the generated statement but how do you get to this statement.

Comment: Oh sorry, just added it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
return entityManager().createNativeQuery(jpaQuerySb.toString(), Range.class).getResultList();
```

?

If you build a native query, you have to use the entity manager's appropriate method.

Comment: Sorry made a mistake in my copied code, was not using the query I instanciated with params, but instead rebuilding one from StringBuilder.
Corrected the code in the main post

Comment: To be clear, it works fine with nativeQuery if I changed my String query to be SQL instead of HQL (just as it works in MySql Workbench).
My question is how to make it work with HQL ?