# Call PostgreSQL stored procedure with Java returns null

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have the following stored procedure written in PostgreSQL 9.3 that's working perfectly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getColor(i INT) 
 RETURNS VARCHAR AS $varColor$
    DECLARE varColor varchar;   
    BEGIN
      select color into varColor FROM colors where id = i;
      return varColor;
    END;
    $varColor$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In fact, when I execute `select getColor(2)` in pgAdmin I get the expected value.
I am trying to call it like this from Java (simplified version):

```
String call =  "{ call getColor(?,?) }";
CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall(call);
cstmt.setInt(1, 2);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
boolean hadResults = cstmt.execute();
```

The problem is that `hadResults` is always null.
Any ideas?

Comment: `CallableStatement` is intended for "real" stored procedures. A postgres function is better called by running `select getColor(2)`  using a `PreparedStatement` and `executeQuery()`

Comment: In postgresql a store procedure is created with the create function statement http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/stored_procedures_functions

Comment: @user1820620: That's "stored procedure", not "store procedure". And `CREATE FUNCTION` creates a function, which is almost but not exactly the same.

Comment: thank you, so how to create a "true" stored procedure in postgresql? In the link http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/stored_procedures_functions there are no distinctions

Comment: That link is plain wrong. Postgres does not have "stored procedures" so you cannot create a "true" stored procedure. The claim that a function cannot return multiple result sets is also wrong. This _is_ possible using ref cursors. The claim that you **have** to use a ref cursor to return a result is also plain wrong. You should stick to the official manual.

Comment: Found this one for Oracle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862694/how-to-call-oracle-function-or-stored-procedure-using-spring-persistence-framewo. I do not know PG stored functions, but maybe you should call your function using : String call =  "{ ? =  call getColor(?) }";

Comment: @JoshRomRock: if he/she insists on using the unnecessary `CallableStatement` interface, then yes that would be the correct way. However, using a plain `select` makes more sense as this is a function, not a stored procedure.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I don't insist, I will follow your advices and let you know.thank you

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql stored procedures concept is something different than other vendors like Oracle.
Basically what in Oracle is called store procedure in Postgresql can be a function, and to call a function in Java is better to use prepare statements and executeQuery methods like in the following example

```
String call =  "select getColor(?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(call);
pstmt.setInt(1,1);
Resultset resultset = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

Thank you to all the guys who helped in the question comments!

Comment: I would recommend `"String call =  "select getColor(?)";`  and `connection.prepareStatement()` instead